# @Value not working as expected in mapper abstract class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mapstruct

So I have a `mapstruct` mapper in my app, which has source to destination pojo mappings. I perform some logic inside the `@AfterMapping` class using the value from the `@Value` like below. But it seems like the value is not being fetched and hence its `set as null` What am I missing here?

```
@Mapper
abstract class Student{

@Value("${spring.application.name}")
String appName;

abstract StudentModel convert(StudentDTO Studentdto);

@AfterMapping
void postConvert(@MappingTarget StudentModel studentmodel,StudentDTO studentDTO) {
studentmodel.setName(appName)

}
```

**application.yml**

```
spring:
   application:
       name: ABC
```

Comment: You can try and replace `@Mapper` with `@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")`,

Answer (score 0):

I have never used mapstruct, but spring injects values only into beans (like @Service, @Repository, @RestController or @Component). Your student class is not a bean, moreover it is an abstract class. Probably you need to pass appName from some service and use @Value there